# iOS Date() returns incorrect value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am using the below code to get the iOS device date.

```
    let today = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
    let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
    print("todayDate : \(currentDate)")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
    let currentMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
    print("currentMonth : \(currentMonth)")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"
    let currentYear = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
    print("currentYear : \(currentYear)")
```

When I am changing device date in iPhone setting 29-12-2019 or 30-12-2019 or 31-12-2019. currentMonth and currentDate values are correct. but, the currentYear return value is 2020 instead of 2019. Kindly suggest me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year. 
>   see this for help : [Challenges of DateFormatters](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/challenges-of-dateformatters/)

use your dateformat

> "yyyy" is ordinary calendar year.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
```

instead of

> "YYYY" is week-based calendar year.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"
```

finally as per your question ,

```
   let today = Date()
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()     
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
   let currentYear = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
   print("currentYear : \(currentYear)")
```

you get the output as

[image]